# Selenium + C# : How to add list value in cookies?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

This is my code:

```
 IList<IWebElement> program = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='PnlGAPAncillaryPrograms']/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]"));
 driver.Manage().Cookies.AddCookie(new Cookie("Name", program ));
 var cookie = driver.Manage().Cookies.GetCookieNamed("Name");
```

What I want to do is, add the List "program" in to the cookie.

Is it possible to do so? If yes, how? What is the correct way to do this?